# Do non-conservative forces affect the conservation of mechanical energy?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, energy-conservation, conservation-laws, friction

Regarding the law of conservation of mechanical energy ($E_m$). Determine True or False for the following statements

1. It only requires that conservative forces are applied
2. It is conserved even if non conservative forces are applied
3. It is not conserved if there is friction

My answer was

1. T – If only conservative forces are applied the mechanical energy is conserved
2. F – if there are non conservative forces that do work, the mechanical energy is not conserved
3. T – As long as the kinetic friction is the only one doing work

This was a question on my exam of intro to physics and I got it wrong, I don’t understand why, my professor didn’t give me feedback either. I consider that my arguments are solid

Comment: You might want to expand on your last argument.

Comment: Remember that static friction doesn't dissipate mechanical energy, so 3 is false (and even if it were true, your justification is wrong, because even if kinetic friction isn't the only force doing work, mechanical energy is typically not conserved then).

Answer (score 1):

The last one is actually False.

You are right if you say that conservation of kinetic energy does not apply here but this applies almost nowhere.

We shall talk about total energy conservation.
This is generally true for everything that exists. In the specific case of friction, we convert kinetic energy to heat energy. Heat energy again can be understood as kinetic energy of particles so maybe it’s true?

About the first one, you can argue yes and no. Obviously it’s true that it’s preserved when conservative forces are applied but even if they are not conservative but cancel each other out, this would be true as well. But generally it would be false if the forces would not be conservative

Comment: The question asks to evaluate the statements for mechanical energy and heat energy (although of kinetic origin) is not generally considered as mechanical energy, so the last statement is true.

Comment: If we only consider mechanical energy without energy types on microscopic level, yes

Comment: Exactly! And from the question, I suppose OP is only considering the macroscopic aspect of mechanical energy, however it might be better to ask the OP.

Comment: yes only microscopic aspects. It is my first a introductory class so I don't think the professor want's to consider microscopic aspects

Comment: Then kinetic energy is not conserved because of friction